# Get only first of two arrays which are combined in one array

Tags: php, arrays

If i var_dump my array `$array_name` i get the following:

```
array(4) {
  ["lounge"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["terrasse"]=>
  string(12) "ab 18:00 Uhr"
 ["vorverkauf"]=>
  string(12) "ab 18:30 Uhr"
  ["titles"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["lounge"]=>
    string(6) "Lounge"
    ["terrasse"]=>
    string(14) "Außenbar"
    ["vorverkauf"]=>
    string(18) "Vorverkauf im 1.UG"
  }
}
array(4) {
  ["lounge"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["terrasse"]=>
  string(12) "ab 18:00 Uhr"
  ["vorverkauf"]=>
  string(12) "ab 18:30 Uhr"
  ["titles"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["lounge"]=>
    string(6) "Lounge"
    ["terrasse"]=>
    string(14) "Außenbar"
    ["vorverkauf"]=>
    string(18) "Vorverkauf im 1.UG"
  }
}
```

As you can see these are two arrays BUT they are not within one "master" array. 
I'd like to have only the first of these to arrays.

So i tried

`var_dump($array_name[0])` which returns NULL

What am i missing?

At the end I would like to get ONLY from the first array the following value:

Something like `$array[0]['titles]['lounge']` should output `Lounge`

Comment: Post your code where contains logic which create `$array_name` please

Comment: You don't have an array[0]. You have $array["titles"]["lounge"]

Comment: looks like you var_dump same array twice; if you execute var_dump($array_name['titles]['lounge']) what you get?

Comment: @BogdanMantescu this would return two strings which contain the word "Lounge". But still these are TWO strings string(6) "Lounge"
string(6) "Lounge"

Comment: maybe you are in a repetitive statement (for, foreach, while..)

Comment: and how can i get only the values of the first arrays?

Comment: is only one array, but printed by var_dump() twice, so you can use $array_name['titles]['lounge']

Comment: i was sure i tried this one..... thanks a lot! it is working!

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each one printing the value 
And this is because you don't define a key for arrays with in array name

```
foreach( $array_name as $sub_array_name){
 echo $sub_array_name["titles"]["lounge"];

}
```